# C++ - How to replicate std::fixed syntax with own class

Tags: c++, function, stream, overloading

I would like to replicate `std::fixed` syntax

```
std::cout << std::fixed << ...;
```

but with my own parser class

```
parser >> skip >> i;
```

and I am not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I've looked at `std::fixed` syntax in `<iostream>` to see how it was done and still can't get it working.

Here's a short example of a parser with the syntax I'd like to achieve.

```
struct parser
{
   void skip()
   {
      // skip
   }

   parser &operator>>(int i)
   {
      // parse
      return *this;
   }

   // parser &operator>>(parser &p)
   // {
   //   p.skip();
   //   return *this;
   // }
};

parser &skip(parser &p)
{
   p.skip();
   return p;
}

parser p;
int i = 0;
p >> skip >> i;
```

I've overloaded `operator>>` for my parser but it is not the syntax I want.

How can I achieve the syntax with the `skip` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skip` is a function, so you want to overload `operator>>` for a function pointer. Then you simply call the function with the argument `*this`:

```
parser& operator>>(parser& f(parser&))
{
    return f(*this);
}
```

Note that `std::istream` already has support for manipulators. Your global `skip` function can just take and return `std::istream&`. Then you can use `skip` on an already existing `std::istream` or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Working great!